# Angular Multiple Http Call grouping error to parent observable method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, fork-join

I have a question regarding multiple http calls and catching errors when they happen and be able to read them on a parent component.
I need to know which calls failed so that I can retry them on another method but if I can't see them on component level It is somehow impossibe for me to know which call I need to retry

// COMPONENT CALL

```
generateDocuments(documentType: DocumentType, validDocuments: DocumentTemplate): observable<any>{
return this.documentService.generateDocuments(clientId, ClientDescription,documentType, validDocuments)}
```

//SERVICE CALL:

```
generateDocuments(clientId: int, ClientDescription,documentType:DocumentType, validDocuments: DocumentTemplate): observable<any>{

switch(documentType){

documentType.Word:{
return this.getDocumentCall(clientId, ClientDescription, ...)}

documentType.Excel:{
return this.getDocumentCall(clientId, ClientDescription, ...)}
}
```

// This line will throw an error/success one by one depending on when the call complete

```
 private getDocumentCall(clientId: int, clientDescription: string, ....)
    {
    
    return forkjoin([1,2,4,4,5].map((documentId:number) => {
    
    this.http.get('uri'+documentId+'/'+clientId,headers..).pipe( catchError(error => {
                return of(error);
              });
    });
```

my question is how can I know what call succeeded or failed at component level, or be able to bubble all errors/response to component level

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `forkJoin` [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin). I think for you it is better to pass in an object with key value pairs so you can make better identification.

The way you have it, the order will be the same when subscribed for every call (in essence it will still be in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) when subscribed.

Your `catchError` catches errors for the API call and returns a successful error object for whoever `subscribes`.

Something like this should get you started:

```
this.service.getDocumentCall(1, 'hello').subscribe(responses => {
  responses.forEach(response => {
     // check if the response is instance of HttpErrorResponse signalling an error
     if (response instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        console.log('This call failed');
     } else {
        console.log('This call succeeded');
     }
  });
});
```

Edit:

Try something like this:

```
private getDocumentCall(clientId: int, clientDescription: string, ....)
    {
      const calls = {};
      const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      
      // create the calls object
      ids.forEach(id => {
         calls[id] = this.http.get('uri' + id + '/' + clientId, headers...).pipe( catchError(error => {
                return of(error);
              });
      });
      return forkJoin(calls);
    });
```

```
this.getDocumentCall(1, '2').subscribe(response => {
  // loop through object
  for (const key in response) {
    if (response[key] instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      console.log(`Call with id: ${key} failed`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Call with id: ${key} succeeded`);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: where would I loop through the IDs then?

Comment: Thanks a bunch.